# Using AWS Java SDK for listing objects in a Google Storage S3 compatible bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, aws-sdk

We're trying to use the AWS S3 Java SDK to test a possible migration from using AWS S3 storage to Google Storage service

We've configured the Google Storage according to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple)

Configuring the storage using software like [S3 browser](http://s3browser.com/) seems to work.
However, using the following code snippet, there's an IllegalArgumentException :

```
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfig.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
    AmazonS3 myS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().
            withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("MY_ACCESS_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY"))).
            withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("storage.googleapis.com", "default")).
            withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).
            build();
```

This call return the correct response

```
  List<Bucket> buckets = myS3Client.listBuckets();
```

However, this call returns an exception :

```
  myS3Client.listObjects("my-test-bucket");
```

Exception thrown :

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Invalid argument. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1640)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4325)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4272)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4266)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:834)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:803)
```

Any help is appreciated here